# difference between まとめる　and まとめてとらえる

Tags: words

a sentence goes as follows:
全体をまとめてとらえるのでなく、‘「‘a1->b1, a2-> b2]のように対応する関係にあることを示す。
(an explanation of a type of expression from a text book.

Would I be right in thinking by appending まとめる with とらえる , it changes from meaning 'summarise/ put all together', to something like 一概にいう?

A kind of guess but not too sure about the nuance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you forcibly find difference, in comparison, まとめる feels like you gather scattered things with your hands while まとめて捉える does that you just catch them in your view without actually touching.